# Colon expected in .sql file

Tags: java, spring, vert.x

Pretty new to using Spring with Vertx

I have this users.sql file in the resources dir:

[image]

the code is exactly:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS USER;

CREATE TABLE USER(
  id INTEGER,
  description VARCHAR2(1000)
);

INSERT INTO USER (id, description) VALUES (1, 'product 1');
INSERT INTO USER (id, description) VALUES (2, 'product 2');
INSERT INTO USER (id, description) VALUES (1, 'product 3');
INSERT INTO USER (id, description) VALUES (4, 'product 4');
```

anyone know why it doesn't like the syntax?

Comment: It's not expecting a colon character, the IDE is getting confused and not printing a value in `expected: {}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USER is a reserve key-word in your SQL engine.
Please try to give some other name to your table.

Answer (score 2):

It could be 1 one the reasons below:
1- the word "USER" is an SQL operator, so it cannot be used without **backticks**. `USER`
2- not every SQL server supports 'VARCHAR2' type, try 'VARCHAR'.